# How to analyze the gas used throughout the execution of an Ink! transaction?

Tags: ink

We are reaching an out-of-gas error in one of our Ink contracts and are interested to investigate the gas used throughout the execution. Is there a way to query for the gas consumed throughout the execution of a contract or for a specific method?

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of some gas used function, but I would suggest using `ink_env::gas_left` function to see how much gas is left in between the calls and then analyze.